# ¿Varias consultas en una vista MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**Hola chicos¡**

Mi consulta es que quiero hacer una vista donde pueda almacenar datos en diferentes item, y definiéndole un nombre a cada item con `AS` en MySQL:

Ejemplo:

```
    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(parada_tiemp_mp))) as totalhr_mp FROM materiaprima 
    union SELECT TIME_FORMAT(totalhr_mp, "%r") AS Tiempo FROM sumahorasparadas;
```

Pero ese resultado me lo da en un solo item `AS: totalhr_mp`.

y yo quisiera que cada consulta tenga su propios campos en la vista, por ejemplo un `as: totalhr_mp`  otro `as: Tiempo`.

No sé cómo se haría, intenté con `union` como muestro anteriormente, pero el resultado lo da en la misma item:**totalhr_mp**.

lo que hice fue sumar todas las horas de la bd, y mostrarlas en un vista,
luego formatie ese resultado para obtener la hora en am/pm.(pero en vista separadas y quiero saber si se puede hacer en una sola vista), lo que intento hacer es que le aparesca al usuario el resultado ya formatiado directamente desde mysql, para no complicarme desde java.

Comment: UNION lo que hace es unir dos consultas, utilizando como nombre de campo el primero que encuentra y luego concatenando las filas bajo la misma columna si son el mismo tipo de dato. Si mostras que es lo que queres de salida y cuales son tus entradas podemos ayudarte mejor, sobre todo porque suena a que queres solucionar un problema de tu vista haciendo un query raro, y no es lo ideal.

Comment: Amigo, te tengo la solución pero me gustaría que pudieras actualizar la pregunta con el esquema de tus tablas podría publicar la respuesta.

Comment: de salida yo quiero que cada consulta select semuestre en un item diferente, porque lo que estoy haciendo en la primera consulta es sumar las horas que tengo almacenadas en la bd, y en la segunda consulta  formateo el resultado de esa suma para que las muestre en formato am/pm, tenga otra vista donde se guarda el total y otra donde se formatea a horario am/pm, quiero unirla en una sola vista. ya que esto de las operaciones con horas hasido un dolor de cabeza, no he encontrado otra solucion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas reunir diferentes consultas en una sola para almacenarlas en una vista, te recomiendo hacer subconsultas dentro de la consulta.

Es decir, si hacemos la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
(
SELECT NOW()
) AS tiempo,
(
SELECT MONTH(NOW())
) AS Mes_Actual,
(
SELECT YEAR(NOW())
) AS Anio_Actual
```

Esto dará una resultado como:

```
tiempo |    Mes_Actual    | Anio_Actual
........................................

Valor      Valor          | Valor
```

Si quisiéramos hacer una vista de todas estas consultas unidas en una sola, haríamos:

```
    CREATE VIEW ejemplo_vista AS 
    SELECT
    (
    SELECT NOW()
    ) AS tiempo,
    (
    SELECT MONTH(NOW())
    ) AS Mes_Actual,
    (
    SELECT YEAR(NOW())
    ) AS Anio_Actual
```

Con esto consegurías crear una vista de subconsultas que puede ser llamada como:

```
SELECT * FROM ejemplo_vista
```

Solo queda adaptar las consultas que necesites con lo antes explicado. Saludos.

Comment: una preguna, y cuando la consulta es para obtener campos de otra tabla como se haria alli, ya que me sale un error de sintaxis.

Comment: SELECT
(
SELECT fechas FROM fecha ORDER BY fechas
) AS fechas,
(
SELECT count(fechas) FROM fecha order BY fechas
) AS total_fechas;    no se que esta mal en la consulta, me debuleve que la  vista aroja mas de 1 row

Comment: Pega en tu bd las consultas para ver cuál te regresa más de una fila como resultado. Es un error común cuando manejas subconsultas, sin embargo, trata de hacer uso de los GROUP_BY dependiendo de la lógica de tu consulta, así como tal vez usar algún LIMIT 1 para forzar regresar solo un resultado. También, a modo de debuggear o quizá también de evitar este error común, utiliza la función GROUP_CONCAT() para que en caso de haber subconsultas con más de 1 fila de resultado te las junte separadas por un delimitador (es decir, todos esos resultados separados por algún símbolo como una coma, etc).